# C# Settings Saving?

Tags: c#, settings

I asked a question earlier about which method for saving would be better, I decided I'd try something else because no one had a real response to something that'd work for me.

So, I want to try saving custom `.xml` files into the *AppData* directory, in a nicely order like:

```
AppData\Local\Program\Downloads
AppData\Local\Program\Settings
```

*Settings Directory:*

```
AppData\Local\Program\Settings\One
AppData\Local\Program\Settings\Two
AppData\Local\Program\Settings\Three
```

etc...

How can I do this in Windows Form **without** using `Settings.settings` as those don't have the right requirements I need.

Comment: More people would answer your questions if you Accept some answers!

Comment: You can get the AppData directory like this:
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my article on Code Project.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/user_options_in_xml.aspx